# Writing for loop in r to combine columns that has matching names (with little variance)

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have a data frame where column names are duplicated once. Now I need to combine them to get a proper data set. I can use `dplyr` select command to extract matching columns and combine them later. However, I wish to achieve it using `for` loop.

```
#Example data frame

x <- c(1, NA, 3)
y <- c(1, NA, 4)
x.1 <- c(NA, 3, NA)
y.1 <- c(NA, 5, NA)

data <- data.frame(x, y, x1, y1)

##with `dplyr` I can do like 

t1 <- data%>%select(contains("x"))%>%
mutate(x = rowSums(., na.rm = TRUE))%>%
select(x)
t2 <- data%>%select(contains("y"))%>%
mutate(y = rowSums(., na.rm = TRUE))%>%
select(y)

data <- cbind(t1,t2)
```

This is cumbersome as I have more than 25 similar columns

How to achieve the same result using for loop by matching columns names and perform `rowSums`. Or even simple approach using `dplyr` will also help.

Comment: Are you sure your column names are the same, and not just similar? (Ie STNCODE & STNCODE vs STNCODE & STNCODE_1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `split.default` to split based on the substring of the column names into a `list` and then apply the `rowSums`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
data %>%
    split.default(str_remove(names(.), "\\.\\d+")) %>%
    map_dfr(rowSums, na.rm = TRUE)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#      x     y
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1
#2     3     5
#3     3     4
```

---

If we want to use a `for` loop

```
un1 <- unique(sub("\\..*", "", names(data)))
out <- setNames(rep(list(NA), length(un1)), un1)
for(un in un1) {
     out[[un]] <- rowSums(data[grep(un, names(data))], na.rm = TRUE)
 }
as.data.frame(out)
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(x = c(1, NA, 3), y = c(1, NA, 4), x.1 = c(NA, 
3, NA), y.1 = c(NA, 5, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Works amazingly well! If you do not mind, how can we achieve the same results using `for` loop?

Comment: @BalachandarKaliappan thankjs, updated with a for loop

Answer (score 3):

Using `purrr::map_dfc` and `transmute` instead of `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
purrr::map_dfc(c('x','y'), ~data %>% select(contains(.x)) %>% 
                                     transmute(!!.x := rowSums(., na.rm = TRUE)))

  x y
1 1 1
2 3 5
3 3 4
```

Comment: Is this answer reproducible for other situations as well? For me, the codes looks like it works only for this situation.

Comment: It may work, but this not how SO works, we can not imagine these situations from the top of our heads, unless you mentioned them.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply @A.Suliman. I appreciate your help. In future, I shall write it in detail.